# Socket doesn't receive any packet

Tags: c#, networking

I'm making a client who connects to server and then it waits for server to send UDP packets. Whenever server sends udp packet, client(I) need to send back the same packet I received. I started my server, used wpe to catch packets, and this is how it looks like:

```
49  0.0.0.0:10052  :0  9  SendTo   0000  A9 84 09 0A 00 AC 48 C4 D3    ......H..

50  :0  0.0.0.0:10052  9  RecvFrom   0000  A9 84 09 0A 00 AC 48 C4 D3  ......H..
```

Server is hosted on port 10052. So what I tried is this:

```
 Socket jj2ClientUDP = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
 SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), 10052);
     jj2ClientUDP.Connect(ep);
     jj2ClientUDP.BeginReceive(buffer1, 0, buffer1.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(received), jj2ClientUDP);
}

private void received(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            byte[] receivedData = new byte[1500];
            receivedData = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;
            jj2ClientUDP.SendTo(receivedData, ep);
            byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1500];
            jj2ClientUDP.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length, 0, ref ep, new AsyncCallback(received), jj2ClientUDP);
            MessageBox.Show("Received and sent back.");
            }
```

I'm doing something wrong, cuz it doesn't send packets back. The messagebox doesnt appear. Please help.
Thank you in advance.

If I put MessageBox on the beggining of received, nothing happens as well.

Comment: If you move the messagebox code to the beginning of the received method, does it then show?

Comment: Don't you need to call `jj2ClientUDP.EndReceive(ar)` before sending a response? Also, if you debug through this, are any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Further to my previous comment, it looks like the line `receivedData = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;` should throw an exception since `ar.AsyncState` appears to be a `Socket` instance in this code.

Comment: @CodingYoshi edited.

Comment: @wablab no exceptions.

Comment: @user3751721, have you confirmed that the `received` method actually gets called by placing a breakpoint on it and debugging through the code?

Comment: Why IP address is all zeros? `0.0.0.0:10052`